# CSS column issues with box shadow

Tags: html, css, gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using CSS Column count to create a grid. However, I cannot fix a slight issue regarding the box shadow I am using.

It seems that the top row of each column has the top clipped off. This doesn't effect the border, but only box shadow.

heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3947/

If you look closely you can see that the top row items have no shadow, and it looks like it has been clipped to the bottom of the column? Scroll to the bottom of the container and you will see the top part of the shadow there.

Any ideas how to fix?

Some back up css:

```
#builds {
  width: 96%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.cols {
  -moz-column-count:3;
  -webkit-column-count:3;
  column-count: 3;
}
.item {
  height: auto;
  width: 99%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -o-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

<div id="builds" class="cols">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Wenman,738.jpeg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Padding to the top of the columns container does not work. And if I give the items class a margin of 10, it works on the first element but not the others.

Comment: The box shadow is actually rendered outside the borders of an element, I would say that adding a top padding to your columns will fix it.

Comment: Negative, that does not fix the issue. I'll add in to my question what I have tried.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding the question: if you don't have any shadow on the top, what is actually getting clipped?

Comment: There SHOULD be some on the top, its there on all the other items but the top row.

Comment: Don't you have to have negative `y-offset` to have the top shadow? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pnrv7byy/2/

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought I'm not seeing well since I wear glasses, But I think the problem is that you have two `box-shadow`s with both `y-offset`s are positive. If you want to have a shadow on top of the element, the `y-offset` should be negative:

```
box-shadow: 0 -1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Is this what you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/pnrv7byy/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at this problem myself for quite some time before I noticed `box-shadow` was the source of inconsistent balancing in Webkit between same size boxes in my layout.

I believe the problem is this: Webkit (and Blink) have a bug with `box-shadow` and column where `box-shadow` affects layout calculation and messes up the column flow.

Currently it appears that Safari 9 and Blink 46 Versions (perhaps earlier versions) have fixed part of column flow issues in terms of the overall column heights calculation. However unlike IE, Edge and Firefox, Safari 9 and Chrome still count the `box-shadow` as an extra gap. And Chrome in particular cuts off the box-shadow, also apparently ignoring `break-inside`...

Here is my alternative to Nadeemmnn's solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/hexalys/DTcHh/14980/

The difference is I avoid an extra inside `div` wrapper for the `box-shadow`. Instead, I use a `margin-bottom` roughly equal to the box-shadow dimension +0.5px in this case. And I use `margin-top` for the top margin with `inline-block`(s) instead of blocks. Which is what i'd recommend inside columns.

It's hackish, but it seems to work ok for me so far.

PS: I'll go ahead and report those browser bugs if not already filed.

Answer (score -1):

**Here are my two solutions**

**Solution1:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="builds" class="cols">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Wenman,738.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Bassboy,539.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Chino,920.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Wenman,738.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Bassboy,539.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Chino,920.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Chino,920.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Wenman,738.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Wenman,738.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Bassboy,539.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Chino,920.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Bassboy,539.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Chino,920.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Wenman,738.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://buildsanctuary.com/user_uploads/cover_images/Chino,920.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/DTcHh/3971/)

here we have removed the box-shadow for item and added for thumbnail i.e from bootstrap

**Solution2**

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/pnrv7byy/4/)

Comment: check2 demos and rate it